# How to alter the position of a row with specific value in query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have following sample data.

```
trxn_id event_id  timestamp
1         4        111
1        16        121
1         1        110
```

Now, I'd like the event 16 to appear between 4 and 1 in the results with **`order by timestamp desc`**. Means the **result should always be ordered by with time in descending, except event_id=16 row just below the row of event_id=4, no matter what it's time is**.

I was thinking of selecting the event_id=4 result first then union it with the result of selecting rest of the event_id's but they don't maintain the order in which union was applied. What can be done? thanks.

Edit: I'm selecting based upon a specific trxn_id. There can be multiple `event_id=16` in one trxn. All needs to appear just below the `event_id=4`.

Comment: What do u do when there are multiple `event_id = 16`? I'm assuming that you need to do this for every `txn_id`. Will there always be just one `event_id = 4`?

Comment: I'm selecting only on the specific `trxn_id`. But yes, there can be multiple `event_id=16` in one `trxn_id`, all those needs to be just below the `event_id=4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could predefine a hierarchy for `event_id`, first sort by it and then sort by `TIMESTAMP DESC`.

```
ORDER BY CASE event_id
        WHEN 4
            THEN 1
        WHEN 16
            THEN 2
        WHEN 1
            THEN 3
        END
    ,TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Comment: Perfect! Gracious.

Comment: @AnandTyagi : Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I would recommend using arrays:

```
order by array_position(array[1, 16, 4], event_id), timestamp desc
```

Comment: It's certainly cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you have the timestamp of 16 equal to the timestamp of 4 then you can order it by the new timestamp and event ID. There can be a shorter solution using window functions but I'm not sure if it works with postgresql

```
select t1.txn_id, t1.event_id, t1.timestamp, case when t2.min_time is not null then t2.min_time else t1.timestamp end as timestamp2
from table as T1
left join 
(
  select trxn_id, min(timestamp) as min_time
  from table
  group by trxn_id
) as T2
on T1.trxn_id = T2.trxn_id
  and T1.event_id = 16
order by t1.txn_id, timestamp2 desc, t1.event_id, t1.timestamp desc
```

Comment: Thank you, though It seems a little slow and complicated. Can you please give me shorter solution with window functions? I'll try if that works. Also, There's no need to group by as I have the trxn_id for which I need events.